# Regex: Find if a string is substring of another, while ignoring cases, alphanumeric numbers, quotes or any special characters

Tags: java, python-3.x

I am trying tow compare a set of strings to remove duplicate strings. The input is delimited by using "|".

```
Input: 
SHAMA went to jungle|SHAMA went to "jungle" and climbed a tree| shama went to jungle|'SHAMA went to jungle' and climbed a tree?

Output:
SHAMA went to "jungle" and climbed a tree
```

There are some rule to be followed:

1. Leading and trailing whitespace should be ignored
2. Any other block of contiguous whitespace should be treated as a
   single space
3. non-alphanumeric character should be ignored, white space should be
   retained
4. The case of alphabetic characters should be ignored

I am struggling to find a way to ignore quotes ' ', "", ? and upper and lower cases at the same. The output: if any of the string is substring of another, then that string should be deleted. If two strings are same, then smaller string should be kept.

Please let me know, if there is any way.

Comment: Your rules seem to be most easily handled by normalizing the string to follow those rules before trying to match anything with regexes: trim the leading/trailing whitespace, replace contiguous blocks of whitespace with a single space etc.

Comment: I have tried using it using split, function, removing all spaces, but I don't know how to handle quotes while checking for substring, as the final output should be in same format as that of original.